Individual pangram lists for words of lengths 12-letter, 13-letter, 14-letter, and 15-letter
9 letter.
Molybdate Jarovized Squawfish Pickaxing.
10 letter.
Jackknifed Squeezable Playwright Overmixing.
11 letter.
Squawfishes Platemaking Objectivity Deoxidizers.
Now, I'm looking for four more pangrams for wordlengths 12, 13, 14, and 15.
To be clear as clear can be, each list should have only one word length; don't mix and match. This can prove a challenge when certain roots don't exist in specific lengths. EX: stem JUKEBOX or even the simplified JKBX exists in a 7-letter word (Jukebox) and a 9-letter word (Jukeboxes), but not an 8-letter word.
I love data! If you get multiple results, post them all. Don't care if it's 20 lists or 400.
Can any of them reduce to 3 words? A 15-letter list three words long would already be 45 letters; four words long reaches 60.
Of course, it's not just length, but coverage of uncommon letters across a small set of single words, such as VQZ of Ventriloquizes (14), CPFX of Ciprofloxacin (13), and CHQ of Discotheques (12).

(Using YAWL)
It sounds like you're interested in the full list of pangrams. Here it is (102MB zipped text file).



# letters
# pangrams using 4 words




7
0


8
229


9
14902


10
253782


11
537452


12
691867


13
529008


14
15420


15
7394


16
675


17
1388


18
5




You are correct; this is AMAZING. Thank you!

Via integer linear programming (specifically, set covering), here are the minimum numbers of (YAWL) words to cover every letter at least once:
12:

 {'CHEQUERWORKS','EXEMPLIFYING','KATZENJAMMER','OBJECTIVIZED'}

13:

 {'JAWBREAKINGLY','PHOTOOXIDIZES','QUALIFICATIVE','VANQUISHMENTS'}

14:

 {'JUXTAPOSITIONS','MULTIFREQUENCY','SWASHBUCKLINGS','VENTRILOQUIZED'}

15:

{'DERMATOGLYPHICS','DETOXIFICATIONS','OBJECTIVIZATION','QUICKWITTEDNESS'}


Thanks! I presume you got other results, as I found Xylographies Objectivized Infrequently Metalworkers (12) on my own.

Yes, there are thousands of optimal solutions.

There are even 1609 optimal solutions that include Xylographies and Objectivized as two of the four words.
